# Using linq expressions how can I create and return a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, expression-trees, linq-expressions

In C# I am attempting to use linq expressions to generate calls to certain methods. One of the parameters to the method is a delegate. I have the MethodInfo for the method I want to pass as a delegate I just am not sure of the linq syntax for creating delegates.

This is a bit contrived but I hope this shows what I'm trying to do:

```
[C#]
delegate void Example();

object instance = ...;
MethodInfo methodToCall = ...;
MethodInfo methodToReference = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Foo");
var lambda = Expression.Call(
    methodToCall,
    Expression.New(
      typeof(Example).GetConstructor(new [] { typeof(object), IntPtr }),
      Expression.Constant(instance),
      Expression.Constant(/* IntPtr from MethodInfo?? */)));

lambda.Compile()();
```

The problem is that the constructor for a delegate is asking for an IntPtr, I am not sure how to get that! Is there a more direct way to create a delegate object than trying to use the New() expression method?

Comment: Maybe `Expression.Lambda()` instead of `Constant`?

Comment: I just made a little function that accepts Expression<Func<T>> and then passed in a C# lambda. You can look at the expression tree that C# generated and it turns out that C# generates a call to Delegate.CreateDelegate(...) and casts it! Too easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Example e = (Example)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Example), instance, methodToReference);
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. I just had to use linq expressions to generate this code though.